# Removing duplicate rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have ~67 000 rows but i have 12k duplicate rows with different key.

I would like to remove duplicates and save only one row.

Table name: seb_societe

Similar columns: nom, phone, adress, zip

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
DELETE
FROM seb_societe AS T
WHERE  T.rowid < ANY (SELECT rowid
                FROM seb_societe AS T2
                WHERE  T.rowid <> T2.rowid
                  AND  T.nom = T2.nom
                  AND  T.address = T2.address);
```

Can anyone advise why my attempt didn't work, or how to achieve my desired outcome.

Comment: Which rowid to keep/delete?

Comment: @jarlh one of the two, i just need to keep one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5):

```
delete
from seb_societe
where exists
    (
    select *
    from
        (
        select 1
        from seb_societe t2
        where t2.row_id > row_id
        and nom = T2.nom
        and address = T2.address
        ) x1
    )
```

Comment: Not works (not "row_id" but "rowid") : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't1
where exists
    (
    select 1
    from seb_societe t2
    where t2.row' at line 2

Comment: Remove the t1 alias everywhere.

Comment: Here is my error : #1093 - You can't specify target table 'seb_societe' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Edit made, MySQL handles the subquery while deleting/updating, so it needs wrapping

Comment: 0 line deleted with this

Answer (score 2):

You can use delete on join:

```
delete s
from seb_societe s
join (
    select nom,
        address,
        max(rowid) as max_rowid
    from seb_societe
    group by nom,
        address
    ) t on s.nom = t.nom
    and s.address = t.address
    and s.rowid <> t.max_rowid;
```

Comment: Work but ... Any idea ? #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: Not sure abt that

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE t1 FROM 
    seb_societe t1 LEFT JOIN seb_societe t2 ON 
    t1.nom = t2.nom AND t1.address = t2.address
WHERE t1.row_id < t2.row_id;
```

try on a back up first...

this should leave the row with the highest row_id of the duplicates.

Comment: Work but ... Any idea ? #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: Ewwww, old style joins

Comment: Wuuuuuuuuuuut ?

Answer (score 1):

DELETE T FROM seb_societe T,seb_societe T2 WHERE  T.rowid < T2.rowid AND  T.nom = T2.nom AND  T.address = T2.address;

Comment: Same problem ... #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: problem is not with the query.Its is with your data.

Comment: i think one of the rows is corrupted,try select * from seb_societe by ranging different you will get the corrupted row

Comment: By ranging ? i have 67 000 lines xD

Comment: then use binary search like,select * from seb_societe limit 67000/2,then

Comment: select * from seb_societe limit 67000/2,67000

Comment: Yes but how can i find this line ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I use a PHP script to delete duplicates lines :

```
global $dbh;
$query='SELECT rowid, nom FROM seb_societe GROUP BY `nom`, `address` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1';
$query = $dbh->query($query);
$i = 0;

$retour=array();

while($resultat = $query->fetch()) {
    $rowid = $resultat['rowid'];
    $suppression = $dbh->exec('DELETE FROM seb_societe WHERE rowid = '.$rowid); 
}
```

Before, i delete all lines in other tables with foreign keys.

Thanks all for your replies.